# MySql Soft delete

Tags: mysql

I have an existing application (with MySQL DB).

I just got a new requirement where I need to delete some records from one of main entity. I dont want to apply hard delete here as its risky for whole application. If I use soft delete I have to add another field is_deleted and because of that i have to update all my queries (like where is_deleted = '0').

Please let me know if there is any smarter way to handle this situation. I have to make changes in half of the queries if I introduce a new flag to handle deletes.

Comment: there is no other way - either a new flag and/or you can extend an existing flag...

Comment: Yes, as per your requirement flag is best choice, othervise you can take a abstract of your table into temporary table and done delete on it for checking.

Comment: Depends what you mean by soft delete and what the risks are for the application. You could create a new table for "deleted" entries and move "soft-deleted" across.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your application can run without any changes. MySQL is [ANSI-SPARC Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI-SPARC_Architecture) compliant . With external schema you achieve [codd's rule 9 "Logical data independence"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules):

> Changes to the logical level (tables, columns, rows, and so on) must
>   not require a change to an application based on the structure. Logical
>   data independence is more difficult to achieve than physical data
>   independence.

You can [rename](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html) your tables and create views with original table names. A sample:

Let's supose a table named `my_data`:

```
REMAME TABLE my_data TO my_data_flagged

ALTER TABLE my_data_flagged 
   ADD COLUMN is_deleted boolean NOT NULL default 0;

CREATE VIEW my_data AS 
   SELECT * 
   FROM my_data_flagged 
   WHERE  is_deleted = '0'
```

Another way is create a trigger and make a copy of erased rows in independent table.

Answer (score 4):

Four suggestions:

1. Instead of using a bit called `is_deleted`, use a dateTime called something like `deleted_Date`... have this value be `NULL` if it is still active, and be a timestamp for the deletion date otherwise.  This way you also know *when* a particular record was deleted.
2. Instead of updating half of your queries to exclude deleted records, create a view that does this filtering, and then update your queries to use this view instead of applying the filtering everywhere.
3. If the soft deleted records are involved in any type of relationships, you may have to create triggers to ensure that active records can't have a parent that is flagged as deleted.
4. Think ahead to how you want to eventually hard-delete these soft-deleted records, and make sure that you have the appropriate integrity checks in place before performing the hard-delete.