# Modify query to exclude soft deleted records

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

Python code part that contains query:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user=sql_username,

        passwd=sql_password, db=sql_main_database,

        port=tunnel.local_bind_port)

query = '''select * from users;'''

df_user = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
```

I need to to modify query to exclude the soft deleted records. How modified query should look like?

Comment: What do you mean by "soft deleted records", do you mean something like what was [discussed in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901905/mysql-soft-delete)?

Comment: @metatoaster Yes I mean how to exclude soft deleted ones that are discussed in the thread that you had pointed?

Comment: Was a new view created as outlined there? If so just select from the view, otherwise modify the query to check for the flag which was used to mark a record as soft deleted.

Comment: @metatoaster Flag was used ‘deleted_at’ is NULL. How query should look like in this case?

Comment: @metatoaster do you think `query = '''select * from users; where deleted_at= 0;'''` will be correct?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE deleted_at is NULL;` if a live record indeed has `NULL` for `deleted_at`.  Invert the search to find deleted records, i.e. `WHERE deleted_at is not NULL`.